# Android Studio - Multiple occurrences of same module

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm installing react-native-firebase, async-storage and react-native-maps on a project.

All the modules from NPM contain the character @ at the beginning of their name and I think this produces the below error.

Can anyone please tell me how to efficiently remove the duplicate modules?  Android studio keeps on adding them.

```
ERROR: The modules ['android-@react-native-firebase_app', 'react-native-firebase_app'] point to the same directory in the file system.
Each module must have a unique path.


ERROR: The modules ['android-@react-native-firebase_messaging', 'react-native-firebase_messaging'] point to the same directory in the file system.
Each module must have a unique path.


ERROR: The modules ['android-@react-native-community_async-storage', 'react-native-community_async-storage'] point to the same directory in the file system.
Each module must have a unique path.


ERROR: The modules ['android-@react-native-firebase_analytics', 'react-native-firebase_analytics'] point to the same directory in the file system.
Each module must have a unique path.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest Android Studio solved it.  I upgraded to Android Studio v3.6

Comment: Surprisingly, the only solution! Thanks!